# Change screenshots of app after submission

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a simple question.

Can I change Screenshots of my app in the "Metadata and Uploads" section in itunesconnect.apple.com, **after submission of app ?** (At very first my app was rejected by apple  after rejection, i made some changes in the app and then again uploaded new binary using "Ready to upload binary" button in `iTunesconnect` while uploading he didn't ask me for updating screenshots..)

If not then, do i need to reupload binary ?

My current status in itunesconnect shows `Waiting for review`

Thanks.

Comment: yes you can change your screen shots.. so don't worry

Comment: Yes don't worry you can change your svreenshots....before acceptance.

Comment: yes no need of worries you can change them

Comment: You can change. Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451338/1151916

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Even more recently (who knows when...) apparently you can change screenshots again while the app is waiting for review.

---

More recently (2015 or earlier), you cannot change screenshots even while your app is "waiting for review."

---

You are not allowed to change them *after the app has been approved* so be quick. See [this news release](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=1092013a) by Apple:

This move is thought to be [a way to deter spammers](http://www.macstories.net/links/app-store-screenshot-changes/) from posting a fake app and then changing the screenshot to mimic an existing popular app.

Comment: My current status in itunesconnect shows `Waiting for review` if i change now, will it be changed ?

Comment: Yes, according to the available information, since the new version has not been approved yet.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate unfortunately.

Comment: @borrrden See below.. added an answer yesterday.

Comment: @PaulPeelen What is inaccurate about my answer?  Is it that I left out the part about how you can edit them again once you make a new version?

Comment: @borrrden again, its stated in my answer below. You are not allowed to change them after you submit your answer for review (meaning status: Waiting for review). You are only allowed to remove screenshots, not add any. Please, read my answer. Either way, at the time you wrote your answer, it was correct. Apple changes this from time to time.

Comment: thats bad because you can change the release notes even after approvel. if you ant you can spam also there =)

Comment: You can change screenshots. Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451338/1151916

Answer (score 9):

Update after talking to Apple:

On 2015-08-18 @ 12:30pm EST, the answer is still NO -- but there is hope.

I spoke with Apple on Monday, 2015-08-17 and after investigating the issue, they explained that iTunes Connect Screenshot uploading has a temporary error due to ongoing updates to iTunes Connect as aforementioned at WWDC.  They are now aware of the issue and their engineers will restore the legacy functionality allowing us upload new images while Waiting For Review, as soon as possible.  Meanwhile, if one needs to modify screenshots, simple "Remove this version from review", change the screens, then re-click "Submit For Review".

I hope this helps.
:-)

On 2015-08-16 @ 2:48am EST, the answer is NO.

I can not edit, add, or remove screen shots in either Safari, Chrome or Firefox at time for status "Waiting For Review".  I cannot do it before editing anything else - like the title or keywords, which ARE editable - nor can I do it after editing anything else.

I have read all of the guidelines provided in the links above in full.  At a certain point, it becomes circular linking regarding editing metadata and app statuses.  Yes, screens are locked when the app is not editable, but all indications are that Waiting For Review is an editable status.  There is nothing stating this is not the case.  Heck, at the top of the App's screen is blatantly states:
"(i) You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review."

However, one CAN NOT do it.  This is a real blow as one will not realize this until it is too late and one is reading these posts - and now one realizes that one has lost the time and must reject and re-queue.  Either that, or go to market with inferior metadata screens.

I will call the contact number in the morning at 7am PST.  If anything changes, I will update this post. If not updated, one can assume this is the final status as of this time.

*** Sadly:
If you need to change your meta screens, and you cannot do it, stop hoping, stop reading, I am sorry to say:  You cannot do it.  Cancel the submission, change the version number, change the screens and resubmit the sooner, the better.

:-(

Answer (score 5):

I just discovered this evening that they lock it down when it goes into "In Review".

Answer (score 4):

These "rules" change from time to time, currently (Jun 2015) you can change certain items but not images when you submit for review.

More information about what you can and cannot change is located here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

The last column currently states `Locked`. There it also states:

> General App Information properties are either locked or unlocked.
>   Unlocked properties are always editable. Locked properties are only
>   editable when your app is in an editable state. The tables in this
>   section indicate whether a property is locked or unlocked. Changes you
>   make to unlocked General App Information properties are posted
>   immediately (expect 24 hours for a full refresh of the change on the
>   store). See also About App Statuses.

Information about app statuses:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW23

Comment: This reads to me like screenshots can be edited while the app is waiting for review, possibly not once it's in review and not once it's available without a new version. i.e the description can be changed at any time because it's unlocked. Either way the language isn't very clear.

Comment: From personal experience just two weeks ago.. the "editing" part of the screenshots is Removal only. You can not add new screenshots. For me that is only removable. If you want to add new screenshots, you'll have to do it before you submit for review.

Comment: Based on your information about app statuses (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW23) screenshots should still be editable until the App status is In Review.

Comment: I believe you haven't fully read the pages I linked though... based upon my information, the screenshots "editable" status is "locked". Please, [check the first link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2) I posted.

Comment: I just tested this and it appears screenshot changes are still allowed.  I submitted the next release of my app for review without the screenshots updated.  Now it's in "Waiting For Review."  I was able to delete a screenshot and add a new screen shot.  I clicked save and that was successful.  After saving it gave me this message as well, "You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review."

Answer (score 2):

Apple have recently changed [their guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html). You can apparently no longer delete or change screenshots once an app has changed status to "Waiting for review".

-_-

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change your binary you can change it. You can upload new screenshots by removing existing screenshots if five or replace one.

Comment: you should BE AWARE that changing (uploading a new) Binary will reset your position in the Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change several screenshots for app that is already "Waiting For Review" today. So apparently it's possible again.

Answer (score 0):

While an app is "**Waiting for Review**" state you can change screenshots. I did check it on Friday, 18 October 2019.

Copied from App Store Connect web site:

> You can still edit all information while your version is waiting for
>   review.

Answer (score -6):

Simply yes.

You can upload/change the screenshots after application approved.

Even you can also change price and description of the app.

But you can not change the category of the app.

So, at the moment, if you have uploaded 2 screenshots, then after app approval, you can upload other 3 screenshots or change the existing 2 screenshots as well.

Hope, you have an idea.

Cheers!

Comment: "You can upload/change the screenshots after application approved."  This is not correct as of January 9, 2013.

Comment: @NishantB please update your answer rather than just commenting

Comment: It is not an update. The answer as wrong from the beginning the answer is dated Feb 7th, 2013.

Comment: still not valid - Nov 2015