# Updating iTunesArtwork and screenshots for published app

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, itunesartwork

I have a published app on app-store, which appears in iTunes as expected. The product logo has changed recently, hence I am supposed to update all graphics.
I changed all icons and republished the app. I now notice that the search result in iTunes for the app shows the older icon. The "Large Icon" in itunes connect also sows the older icon.

Upon Googling, it turned out that I need to update the iTunesArtwork file. Where shall I put that file, prior to Archiving it and preparing the app submission through XCode.

Also, I need to update the four screenshots of the app that appear in iTunes. How do I change that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change screenshots of app after submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745633/change-screenshots-of-app-after-submission)

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to change the Screenshots now. How about changing the "Large Icon" (aka iTunesArtWork)? Shall I just drop a 1024x1024 png into my app source-tree in Xcode and name it as iTunesArtwork ... will that be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out ... while registering for an update, iTunesConnect provides an option to change the Large Icon and the Screenshots. No need for adding any files in the app source tree.